# change DNS server programatically in C#

Tags: c#, dns, dhcp, dnsmasq

I had a web service in two locations location1 and location2
now my application should access the service from location1 and if it is not available at location1 then only it must goes to location2
can i configure the dns based on my requirement using C# pragmatically

Answer (score 0):

On DNS, you can configure duplicate host record to point to different IP to create the load balancing effect, but you cannot detect the "not available status" by using DNS. Even you can configure the DNS record programatically, DNS still take time to refresh the local cache and server cache.